# I'm trying to read file in java it works if i just created the file but after while it will not work

Tags: java, file, tomcat, nio, readfile

im facing little weird proplem

i have a service that read file from local server i used java.nio.file for that

it works perfectly if the file just created or uploaded to the folder, if the file is old it will give me this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/mnt/A/B/123.png' does not exist
```

and to let the old files work again i need to ssh the server and open the directory and list files

after i do that it return working for a while then it stops again and gives the same above error

the server that I'm using is Apache Tomcat/9.0.36
this is my code

```
return Files.readAllBytes(getPath(resourceLoader, uploadDir + "/" + directory + "/" + fileName));
```

i tried to use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils but no luck I'm getting the same issue

```
return org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(getPath(resourceLoader, uploadDir + "/" + directory + "/" + fileName).toFile());
```

Comment: that should not happen. check filename is same or not.

Comment: Do you close the File that you read before you (Try again)?  I dont understand what you mean by the file is (Old).   Show more code

Comment: Could be a problem on the OS side (?): as it is a mounted drive a temporary unmount/remount may give problems.

Comment: @priyranjan the file is working sometimes so i don't think its naming or path issue

Comment: @SusanMustafa i mean by old is that the file was uploaded to the directory before more than 3 hours  , if the file just uploaded it will work fine. i have no more code to share its just one line method

Comment: @JoopEggen you could be right and i talked with the operation guy that is responsible for the server he replied that there is other project that are using the same methodology that I'm using and they didn't face problems. i checked there code also they have the same code that i used

Comment: @MLK again i don't agree with you . you r saying its working with others but not with you. then there must be problem somewhere. at the same time how  system will do partiality.. sounds funny. check somewhere you would be making mistake.. here code is not there so cant help.

Comment: @priyranjan thank you for your post again  and i appreciate that you are trying to help, its working for me and others but after i ssh the server and open the directory and after while it start not working again . the code that i shared is the full code of the method there nothing more i can share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was fixed by restarting the server that is mounting the files